# where's the equivalent of connfd (created socket in C) in python's BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, sockets, http, webserver

In C socket programming at the server-side, after a connection is accepted we can get a handle of the new socket (who is transmitting the data) by "connfd" which is the return value of "accept".

Now I'm trying to implement a web server with Python, I have a handler based on BaseHttpRequestHandler, who handles the requests with the do-Get method.

How can I get ahold of the socket that is transmitting data now (the socket created after the accept and not the one created after bind)?

The reason I need the socket is that I need to read TCP_info from getsockopt with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found it! It is "self.request"!! Confusing style of naming.